# How to specify the type of a field on insert in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Examining the Mongo docs, I can't find how to specify a type on insert.

I am sure it is something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 9):

You specify the type on insert by the type of the value you're inserting. It's not like a RDMS where you have to specify the field type beforehand.

For example:

String: `{"foo": "bar"}`

Number: `{"price": 5.25}`

Hash: `{"foo": {"bar": true}}`

Array of strings: `{"pets": ["cat", "dog"]}`

ObjectID: `{"_id": ObjectId('4f0c76e46794dc6453000001')}`

Time: `{"created_at": ISODate("2011-02-02T20:41:22Z")}`

All of those are examples of how different types are stored by what you pass into the hash. There is also [this page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions) on the MongoDB site that has more examples of this.

Comment: One caveat worth adding: if you specify number "as is" in MongoDB shell, it will store a floating point number. Use `{"count": Number(10)}` to store an integer value

Comment: So typing is handled by the driver itself? BSON uses different types overlaid on the different native types (http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) I'm looking for UTC datetime insertion...

Comment: How are you communicating with MongoDB, is it through the mongo shell, a driver for another language such as Ruby, or are you trying to write a custom driver? the UTC datetime BSON type is just the `ISODate` method in the mongo shell.

Comment: @ZacharyAnker: Common Lisp and Python drivers.

Comment: @PaulNathan: Your driver will handle casting the object type of the language (Lisp or Python in this case) into the BSON type. If you look at the Python driver source, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/_cbsonmodule.c#L461 you can see that it converts DateTime objects into the UTC datetime automatically.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov you may need to specify NumberInt(10) to create a int, as Number(10) in my case defaults to float/double

Comment: Neither Number(10), nor NumberInt(10) worked to store an integer for me.